# Harris corner response in fixed-point integers?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, fixed-point

in harris corner, the response is calculated as follows:
R = det - K * tr^2

where the k (constant) is a floating point number with 0.04 default at few known libraries.

Does this mean that the response (R) needs to be floating point as well?
How then can i produce an integer response then?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the response (R) needs to be a floating point variable too. You can get the integer response using a rounding function if the fractional part of the response is not important for your calculations or you may convert the code to use [fixed point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).